# How to get the column name which is not null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe as below

| ID | Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Some Value |
| 2 | Some Value | null |

I need to add a new column which contains the column name (among Col A and Col B) which is not null.
So the expected dataframe should look like,

| ID | Col A | Col B | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Some Value | Col B |
| 2 | Some Value | null | Col A |

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after creating temp views from your dataframe eg

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_data")
```

you may run the following on your spark session using `newdf = sparkSession.sql("query here")`

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    ColA,
    ColB,
    CASE
        WHEN ColA IS NULL AND ColB IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN ColB IS NULL THEN 'ColA'
        WHEN ColA IS NULL THEN 'ColB'
        ELSE 'ColA Col B'
    END AS result
FROM my_data
```

or just using python

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df = df.withColumn("result",when(
    col("Col A").isNull() & col("Col B").isNull() , None
).when(
    col("Col B").isNull() ,'Col A'
).when(
    col("Col A").isNull() ,'Col B'
).otherwise('Col A Col B') 
)
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need the ANDs in the second two WHEN lines